# Angular, show data to client side with express and mySql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, express

i need help to show my data that stored in mySql database that using Express and Angular. The data array already showed in console. I made the router in app.js. Here is the javacript from server side:

```js
//app.js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabel';
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  })
})
```

Here is the typecript snippets or client side:

```js
//service.ts
getAPI(): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/")
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}

//component.ts

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAPI();
}

Data: string[];

getAPI() {
  this.AppService.getAPI().subscribe(
    data => console.log(this.Data = data),
    error => console.log('server returns error')
  );
}
```

```html
<h2 align="center">MySql</h2><br>
<button (click)="getAPI()"> test</button>
<table>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

I tried to bind like `let Data of Data` but it doesn't works. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: "doesn't work" how? What happens? What do you expect to happen? Can we see the code that fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i just found the solution. `Data: string[] = [];`